# CiviCRM Extension not grabbing latest release

Tags: extension

Submitted a new release and matched the info.xml file to the release number but Civi Extensions directory still hasn't picked up the new release yet. Any ideas why?

https://civicrm.org/extensions/authorizenet-echecknet

Answer (score 1):

You have to turn on the automated-discovery of new releases by including the git url when you edit your extension node, or you can manually tell Civicrm.org about your new release by clicking on the 'Add CiviCRM-native release' link when viewing your extension page while logged in.